# Wrong number of Badges on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

Even though My badges section on my profile at lower section shows 14 badges it is not being reflected in my profile header which is shown on all pages of Stack Exchange Why?

Comment: So when can I expect this to get synched or refreshed? And do you mean browser caching on caching or Server side?

Comment: Looks like the situation has corrected itself on its own. You now have *14* bronze badges on Stack Overflow, according to your profile. The other case I found still has to update, but I suspect that that is going to take care of itself eventually.

Comment: Yes. it seems so ..will keep a watch on it though

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan: indeed, because the other affected account I found is still stuck at 7 instead of 8 badges.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, you are supposed to have 14 bronze badges (11 different types, of which 4 popular question badges), but only 13 are listed.

This looks like a bug with the new badge counts, I easily found [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2280674/paulex10?tab=badges) where the user has 8 different badges (all bronze) but the profile shows 7.

This does not appear to affect the silver Inquisitive badge as of yet, [this user has the correct 9 silvers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546561/eric?tab=badges&sort=class). I can also not find any evidence that this is broken anywhere else but on *Stack Overflow*; here on Meta.SO the badge counts appear to be correct.

There *was* a bug with the [handing out of badges on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262306/notification-that-i-have-earned-curious-badge-but-not-earned-in-reality), which is probably related.

Comment: @Martijin Right. I am concerned about bronze badges only. I have earned bronze badges of 11 types.1 of each type. and 3 extra badges for the same type(Popular Question) so (10 * 1 )+ (1 * 4) = 14 bronze badges. but my header shows 13 badges only

Comment: Ah, indeed. Your count is indeed off by one. I suspect this is the Curious badge throwing a few more problems around on Stack Overflow, let me investigate for a sec.

Comment: Correct this is the badge I just got the notification for. Please let me know